# Can one make an assignment on conditional statement in php?

Tags: php, conditional-statements, conditional-operator, variable-assignment

Can you make an assignment on conditional statement in php as so:

```
if(siteName_err = isValid("sitename", $_POST['sitename'], false))
{
    $siteName = $_POST['sitename'];
}
```

Comment: You guys on stackoverflow Rock hands down!! thanks for turnaround. amazing!

Comment: @JAL, well, in Python assignments are statements, not expressions with a value. But you still can get things done in that language.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes.

I think the most common use scenario for this is when using MySQL. For example:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT username FROM user");
while ($user = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  echo $user['username'] . "\n";
}
```

This works because `$user` is the result from the assignment. Meaning, whatever is stored in your assignment, is then used as the conditional. In other words,

```
var_dump($i = 5);

// is equivalent to

$i = 5;
var_dump($i);
```

Both will print `int(5)`, obviously.

Answer (score 6):

Yes.

Honestly, why don't you try it out? Languages where you're not allowed to do this sort of thing usually generate compiler/parser errors.

PHP takes most of its basic syntactic elements from C, which includes that every assignment returns a value. Therefore this is valid.

Comment: But when you are learning sometimes even if things do seem to work, you cannot be guaranteed that it is proper or correct or won't result in issues down the road. Having a clear and concise answer to the question can certainly be useful.

Answer (score 2):

Yah, you can do that.

If you're asking because you tried it and got a crazy error, try making `siteName_err` a valid variable name by putting a dollar sign `$` before it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes sure  and you can do also the same for while constructs